# Haskell error, expected type

Tags: haskell

Im getting this error on this code!

```
esImpar :: Integer -> Bool
esImpar a = if (a mod 2) /= 0 then True
        else False
```

**Error:**     Couldn't match expected type (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
                           -> (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer'
                with actual type Integer

The function `a' is applied to three arguments,

but its type Integer' has none

In the first argument of (/=), namely (a mod fromIntegral 2)

In the expression: (a mod 2) /= 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mod` by itself is just a function, not an operator; you can use it as `mod a 2` or infix as `` a `mod` 2 ``. (Here you are trying to use `a` as a function, as the error message says.)